# Gradle extract multiple dependencies each to a different directory

Tags: java, gradle

I'm trying to extract multiple dependencies into different directories. I tried the following.

```
configurations {
   cppDependencies
}

dependencies {
   cppDependencies 'com.group:artifact1:1.0"
   cppDependencies 'com.group:artifact2:1.0"
}

task extractDeps(type: Copy) {
    from {
        configurations.cppDependencies.collect {
            zipTree(it)
        }
    }
    into new File(buildDir, "DEP_DIR")
}
```

Obviously this just extracts **artifact1** and **artifact2** under the same **DEP_DIR** directory. But what I would actually want to achieve is extract them under **DEP_DIR/artifact1** and **DEP_DIR/artifact2** respectively.

I tried to put **into new File(buildDir, "DEP_DIR/" + it.artifactId)** under the **zipTree** command but it gives an error.

Is this possible?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I found a working solution.

Don't know if it's the best way, but this is what I came up with:

```
task extractDeps << {
    configurations.cppDependencies.resolvedConfiguration.resolvedArtifacts.each { artifact ->
        copy {
            from project.zipTree(artifact.getFile())
            into new File(project.buildDir, "DEP_DIR/" + artifact.name)
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I came up with a simliar solution in kotlin:

```
dependencies {
    myExtraDependency("org:mydependency-arm64:1.0.0")
    myExtraDependency("org:mydependency-x64:1.0.0")

}

val unzipTask = tasks.register<Copy>("unzip") {
    myExtraDependency.resolvedConfiguration.resolvedArtifacts.forEach {
        from(zipTree(it.file))
        include("**/*.so")
        into ("$buildDir/unzipped")
    }
}
```