# Extract zip file dependencies into separate directories with Gradle

Tags: gradle, android-gradle-plugin

I want to extract multiple zip files that are dependencies for my build.

Right now I have:

```
project.tasks.create(name: 'extractExternalNativeDependencies', type: Copy) {
        from {
            configurations.externalNative.collect {
                zipTree(it)
            }
        }
        into project.file(".externalNativeDependencies")
    }
```

This extracts all the dependencies into the same folder. I want each zip to be extracted into it's own folder instead.

I've seen [Gradle extract multiple dependencies each to a different directory](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18490986/gradle-extract-multiple-dependencies-each-to-a-different-directory) however that "working solution" doesn't really work. It fails if the build is run twice without cleaning and really it shouldn't run if the source zips are up-to-date.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The following `task` configuration expands each dependency into it's own sub-folder:

```
task extractExternalNativeDependencies(type: Copy) {
    configurations.externalNative.collect { dependency ->
        from(zipTree(dependency)) {
            into dependency.name
        }
    }

    into project.file(".externalNativeDependencies")
}
```

Comment: I ended up using resolvedConfiguration instead because that used the dependency name instead of the downloaded file's name:
`configurations.externalNative.resolvedConfiguration.resolvedArtifacts.each {
                    artifact ->
                        project.copy {
                            from(project.zipTree(artifact.file))
                            into new File(outputDir, artifact.name)
                        }
                }`